# Implementing the factory pattern using a pre populated map of objects

Tags: c++, factory, smart-pointers

I have a map of  that maps string ids to a specific implementation of base_object.
Any base_object has a method get_id that returns the id of the object.
and I fill up the map using (pseudo)

```
void addToMap(base_object* obj){
make_pair(obj->get_id(),obj);
}
```

This map acts like a factory, and knows to return the correct object using the id. this is the method declaration for retrieving specific object:

```
base_object* get(string id);
```

All the objects do not have fields only a polymorphic method that behaves differently for each implementation.

I am not sure what is the best way to implement this.

Should the map be a map of `<string,unique_ptr<base_object>>`
In this case when I am returning a base_object using get, is it ok to return a raw pointer to base_object? (I know that the map will keep living so that the object will not get destroyed?) 
or maybe in this case I should use a shared_ptr?
Also, since the object doesn't really have any fields, maybe it is better to return a copy of the object?

Any way I look at this it looks to me like a bad design, and I just can't decide what is the best approach to solve this.
I am very new to cpp so I am not very familiar with all the differences and best usages of pointers...

Comment: Where does the index string come from? External source? Will the map store objects of different most derived classes? Why not use a `std::unordered_map` for amortised O(n) access time?

Comment: Correction: amortised O(1) of course.

Comment: Can you use RTTI for the id instead of coding your own? So, are all the objects really singletons?

Comment: If you return an object with unowning semantics, consider returning it by reference instead of returning a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::unique_ptr<base_object>` and return a const reference to the `unique_ptr`.

Possible implementation:

```
struct Data
{
    std::map<std::string,std::unique_ptr<base_object>> data;

    void add(base_object* obj){
        data[obj->get_id()] = std::unique_ptr<base_object>(obj);
    }

    const std::unique_ptr<base_object>& get(const std::string& id) {
        return data.at(id);
    }
};
```

Use case example:

```
Data data;
data.add(new test1_object{});
data["test1"]->create(); // call a virtual function of base_object
```

---

Note, that this is not really a factory. If the abstract function of `base_object` should be responsible for creating your actual product, you can perhaps do this:

```
struct Factory
{
    std::map<std::string,std::unique_ptr<base_object>> workers;

    void add(base_object* obj){
        data[obj->get_id()] = std::unique_ptr<base_object>(obj);
    }

    Product create(const std::string& id) {
        return data.at(id)->foo(); // call the virtual function here
    }
};

Factory factory;
factory.add(new test1_object{});
Product x = factory.create("test1");
```

Comment: Just a note: The OP already said he uses the first part in his question.

Answer (score 1):

Use `unique_ptr<base_object> const &`. That signals to the caller that what it gets is a handle on a unique object having the id that it requested. Using a `shared_ptr` signals that it may be responsible for keeping the object alive.

Also, there's no need for a `map`: you can use a `set` or `unordered_set` that orders/hashes based on the id. That way, you won't have to store the id twice.

(The thing you're implementing is more of an object pool than a factory.)

Comment: How would you get the object given the ID? The set seems to demand an actual object of the stored type for retrieval...

Answer (score 0):

The standard of the factory pattern is not filled up with objects on start. There are no objects at all. The factory only knows how to create a new object. A possible implementation can do this with a map and registered static! methods of the class ( not a object ).

And a factory should always return a new instance and not a reference or a pointer to an already existent object. The application typically have no idea how to destroy this special kind of copies instead of own instances.

Answer (score 0):

How you best design your thing depends on the use-cases and design constraints:

- If you can guarantee the returned object lives long enough and you can guarantee you'll return an actual object, returning by reference is best (if not having an object to return, there are exceptions. Use where appropriate).
- If you can guarantee the returned object lives long enough *if there is an object to return*, just return by raw pointer.
- If all of the maps elements should live to the end of the program, do not make the map own them unless it lives as long and you want to force it to clean them up: Allocate them statically or dynamically (in the second case you might want to register them with `std::atexit`for cleanup at the end), and let the map only hold an un-owning raw pointer.
- If your program will not be compiled without RTTI and every object is a singleton of its class, consider using `typeid` for the key (at least the name field) instead of a custom string.
- Anyway, you later say the only interesting point of those objects is one single method: Why don't you just use `std::function` for maximum flexibility?
- A `std::unordered_map` has amortised O(1) access, a `std::map` only O(ln(n)).