# Is there any way to create a lookup table at compile time or in preprocessor for a factory creational pattern in c++?

Tags: c++, c++17

I have developed code for image processing that can load, with the help of a json file, different image processing processes depending on the data in the json file. When the file is readed, in some point is reached a function that depending the type of process specified in file it creates the corresponding process that is derived from a base process:

```
    inline BaseProcess* getSpecificObject(QString id, QJsonObject &proc)
    {
        if(id == "ShowImage")
        {
            return BaseProcess::getProcessFromJson<ShowImage>(proc);
        }
        else if(id == "OtherProcess")
        {
            return BaseProcess::getProcessFromJson<OtherProcess>(proc);
        }
        else
        {
            qDebug() << "Unknow ModelObject specified in json file";
            return nullptr;
        }
    }
```

I have in a separate file the above code and it works as expected but there is the real question:
Is there any way to have in BaseProcess header file a static lookup table or a map that can be populated (in compile time) from every derived process header file?

I bassically want to separate the "if-else if" statement from the separate header file to the correspondent portion of the derived classes in order that I can add or remove processes header files without the necessity of modify the code in that file.

The need for this is that this code is intended to be generic and can be ported to another project as-is and you only need to change the processes that the project is going to use. So to avoid human error, I want another developer who has this code to only have to worry about the specific process being developed.

I actually tried to use constexpr and templates and also macros metaprogramming for creating in any way at compile time or with preprocessor the desired lookup table but I have no success.

With macros I know that I can create arrays but I need a behaviour like a map, you specify a key (ex. "ShowImage" string) and it returns the type of the object to be created.

I am using c++17 with msvc 2019 compiler in QT 5.15.

Comment: maybe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23516539/implementing-the-factory-pattern-using-a-pre-populated-map-of-objects

Comment: "you specify a key and it returns the type" This doesn't compile. Functions in C++ do not return types. They return objects.

Comment: You can search an array.

Comment: Just keep it as is. It is okay, and usually the best way to use "if-else-if" trees to do that kind of stuff. More general solution (using preprocessor + templates) is going to ruin code readability and make it way harder to maintain. Just use simple macros to make your "if-else-if" shorter (if needed) or similar tricks. Good luck.

Comment: @FerencDeak I already try something similar but is not what I need because you also need to specify in one header file the "map" and I want to divide the map population.

Comment: @n.m. I know that functions dont return types but in a template for example you can use decltype to deduce types and I thought that It can be possible to do something similar

Comment: @Stas you are right, I dont go completely for preprocessor + templates approach because this increases excessively the readability of the code and losses the "maintain code as easy as possible" philosophy that I am trying to implement. I'll keep the "if-else-if" function afterall. Thank you

Comment: No it is not possible. You cannot have an expression or a function or a variable with a type that depends on program input. Types are fixed at compile time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might change the if-else chain by a map.

```
std::/*unordered_*/map<QString, std::function<BaseProcess*(QJsonObject &)>> processFactory;

BaseProcess* getSpecificObject(QString id, QJsonObject &proc)
{
    if (auto it = processFactory.find(id); it != processFactory.end()) {
        return it->second(proc);
    }
    qDebug() << "Unknow ModelObject specified in json file";
    return nullptr;
}
```

Then either your factory has to know each individual process,

```
std::map<QString, std::function<BaseProcess*(QJsonObject &)>> processFactory = {
    {"ShowImage", &BaseProcess::getProcessFromJson<ShowImage>},
    {"OtherProcess", &BaseProcess::getProcessFromJson<OtherProcess>}
};
```

or your process has to know the factory.

That map can be fed in separated files by global registry.
(it is not compile time done, but it is done before `main`)

```
bool register(QString id, std::function<BaseProcess*(QJsonObject &)> f)
{
    return processFactory.emplace(id, f);
}
```

And then, in ShowImage.cpp

```
static const bool registered = register("ShowImage", &BaseProcess::getProcessFromJson<ShowImage>);
```

and in OtherProcess.cpp

```
static const bool registered = register("OtherProcess", &BaseProcess::getProcessFromJson<OtherProcess>);
```

Comment: Yesterday I tried a very similar try to accomplish what I want and my problem was, when are called the "register" function? keep in mind that the instantiation of specific classes are realized depending what is readed from json file. As I understand, with your approach if there is no instantiation of ShowImage for example, its register function is not called. Or am I wrong and the static const is executed always at start of runtime?

Comment: In both cases, the map is fed at start of program. The register calls are done with global trick, so before the `main`. It is unrelated to the json file.

Comment: I see, I am going to try that but for now I don't have so much time. Anyway, I am going to accept that as the solution and when I can try it, I will post the results. Thank you.